# How do I use MongoDB with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a node.js app and I want to deploy it through GitHub, so I want to use MongoDB Atlas to store my config data so that it can be read and edited by the code. How do I connect my code to MongoDB and use it? I followed some tutorials on how to connect, but they varied wildly and none of them mentioned how to read and write to the database.

Comment: Use the official driver: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow. Could you edit the question to show what you tried, and the precise problem encountered at this stage? You might want to read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to formulate the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using mongoose, and here is great tutorial that explains everything very well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yqu8YF29cU

Here is mongoose official documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit of a "chicken and egg" thing going on here.  On the one hand, you need configuration to connect to Atlas - your connection string is configuration.  On the other hand, you want to store the configuration in Atlas, which is unavailable until you connect.  Below are some steps to connect and interact with  MongoDB Atlas, but the example will have a hard coded connection string including user name and password.  Probably things you would not want hard coded.  This is a trivial example using the driver directly, not using a framework like mongoose.

This test program reads and writes to MongoDB Atlas in a database called `nodetest` in a collection called `mycollection`.

**Prepare a directory**

```
mkdir example
cd example
npm init -y
npm install mongodb
```

Now create a program file in the same directory...

**app.js**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

const uri = 'mongodb+srv://testuser:testuser@cluster0.o3mtz.mongodb.net/nodetest?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const collectionName = 'mycollection';
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function(err) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    consoleLog("Connected successfully to server");
    
    const db = client.db("nodetest");
    const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
    
    // START WITH A CLEARED OUT EMPTY COLLECTION
    collection.deleteMany({}, function (err, deleteResults) {
    
        // VERIFY DELETE COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY
        assert.equal(err, null);
        consoleLog('Delete Results:', deleteResults);

        // CREATE A DOCUMENT
        insertDocument(collection, function(insertResults) {
            consoleLog('insertedDocuments ', insertResults);
            
            // FIND THE INSERTED DOCUMENT
            // CREATE A FILTER BASED ON THE RECENTLY INSERTED OBJECTID
            var filter = {'_id': insertResults.insertedId};
            var sort = {'lastName': -1}; // SORT BY LASTNAME DESCENDING
            var projection = {'lastName': 0}; //EXCLUDE LASTNAME
            
            findDocuments(collection, filter, sort, projection, function(findResults){
                consoleLog('Queried Document:', findResults);
                
                // CREATE AN UPDATE PREDICATE
                var update = {'$set': { 'favoriteColor': 'Green' },
                    '$unset': { 'happinessScore': 1} ,
                    '$addToSet': { 'children': { 'firstName': 'Bob', 'dateOfBirth': new Date('August 10, 2020') } },
                    '$inc': { 'age': 1 }
                };
                
                // UPDATE THE DOCUMENTS
                updateDocuments(collection, filter, update, function(updateResult) {
                    
                    consoleLog('Update Results:', updateResult);
                    
                    // REQUERY THE UPDATED DOCUMENT AND OUTPUT RESULTS
                    findDocuments(collection, filter, null, null, function(findResults) {
                        consoleLog('Queried Document2:', findResults);
                        
                        client.close();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});

const insertDocument = function(collection, callback) {
    var insertedDocument = {
        'createdDate': new Date(),
        'firstName': 'John',
        'lastName': 'Doe',
        'age': 38,
        'happinessScore': 95.6,
        'children': [
            {
                'firstName': 'Timmy',
                'dateOfBirth': new Date('January 1, 2011')
            },
            {
                'firstName': 'Tommy',
                'dateOfBirth': new Date('July 1, 2012')
            },
            {
                'firstName': 'Tammy',
                'dateOfBirth': new Date('November 1, 2013')
            }
        ],
        'spouse': {
            'firstName': 'Jane',
            'lastName': 'Doe',
            'age': 34,
            'happinessScore': 96.3
        }
    }
    
    consoleLog('Inserting:', 'Before insert ObjectId: ' + insertedDocument._id, true)
    
    // INSERT DOCUMENT
    collection.insertOne(insertedDocument, function(err, result) {
        console.log('After insert ObjectId: ' + insertedDocument._id);
        console.log('');
        console.log('');
        assert.equal(err, null);
        callback(result);
    });
}

const findDocuments = function(collection, filter, sort, projection, callback) {
    collection.find(filter).sort(sort).skip(0).limit(1).project(projection).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        consoleLog("Find Documents:", docs);
        callback(docs);
    });
}

const updateDocuments = function(collection, filter, update, callback) {
    collection.updateOne(filter, update, function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        assert.equal(result.modifiedCount, 1);
        assert.equal(result.upsertedId, null);
        assert.equal(result.upsertedCount, 0);
        assert.equal(result.matchedCount, 1);
        
        var modifiedResult = {'modifiedCount': result.modifiedCount,
            'upsertedId': result.upsertedId,
            'upsertedCount': result.upsertedCount,
            'matchedCount': result.matchedCount
        };

        consoleLog('Update Documents:', modifiedResult);
        callback(result);
    });
    
}

function consoleLog(title, body, suppressBlanks) {
    console.log('------------------------------------');
    console.log(title);
    console.log(body);
    
    if(!suppressBlanks) {
        console.log('');
        console.log('');
    }
}
```

**Run the program**

Assuming you are in a shell currently in the directory 'example'...

```
node app.js
```

**Disclaimer**

This program has a bunch of tasks strung together.  Notice some helper methods, like the logging to console.  Purists will complain I did not use promises, or any other more modern async approaches.  That is not the point of this post.  The point is to show the most simplistic approach to working with MongoDB in node using the least amount of framework and tooling.